# How does float guarantee 7 digit precision?

Tags: floating-point, precision, ieee-754

As I know Single-precision floating-point number has 1 bit for sign, 8 bits for exponent and 23 bits for mantissa.

I can understand that 7 digit integers fit 23 bit mantissa and don't loose precision but can't understand how a number like 1234567000000000 fits without loose "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" digits, what is the math behind this?

Comment: You forgot that there is an exponent, which enables values larger than 2^23 or smaller than 1.

Comment: Hi! Do you find the math proof?I want to know it, too.

Answer (score 2):

The IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point format only guarantees that six significant decimal digits will survive a round-trip conversion, not seven. Specifically: If you convert a number that is exactly represented with six decimal digits multiplied by a power of ten to the binary format using correct round-to-nearest rounding, and there is no overflow or underflow, and then you convert back to the nearest number representable with six decimal digits times a power of ten, the result will be the original number.

Generally, when a decimal numeral is converted to binary floating-point, the result might not have the same digits when written in decimal. Your example, 1234567000000000, converts to 1234567008616448, but we might find some case where 123456000… converts to 123455900…, so one of the original digits is different. But the precision supplied by the binary format is such that the result of converting to the binary format is always so near the original value that the difference is never more than half the position value of the sixth digit. For example, converting 123456000… will always produce a result between 123455500… and 123456500… Since the result of the first conversion is always within such an interval, converting it back to six decimal digits, with rounding, always produces the original number.

In order to make this guarantee, the precision of the format must be as fine as one part in 999999. That is because then the numbers in the binary format are so finely spaced that there is at least one in the interval from 9999985… to 9999995…, so the result of converting from decimal to binary can produce a result close enough to the original that converting back produces the original value. With 24 bits in the significand (one implied, 23 explicit), the precision is at least one part in 2<sup>23</sup>, which is 8,388,608. (The significand can go up to 16,777,215, but we do not have a choice about it—it must be normalized, which keeps it in the range from 8,388,608 to 16,777,215.)

One part in 8,388,608 is better than one in 999,999, so six digits can be guaranteed, but it is not better than one in 9,999,999, so seven digits are not guaranteed.

Comment: i already know ur explanations but i need mathematical proof, i have commented for Yann's answer if u interest.

Comment: @spartacus: I don't know about a mathematical proof but it is fairly easy to find problematic 7 digit values which can't successfully round-trip: there are only 4 billion `float`s so it can actually be reasonably tested. An example value which fails to round-trip is `9.536746e-07`: it shares its representation (`0x 35800002`) with` 9.536745e-07`, i.e., one of these two values cannot be correctly restored. The problem can be easily verified, e.g., using the IEEE754 analyzer: https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/

Comment: In “How to Print Floating-Point Numbers Accurately”, Steele/White a formula from "Matula68" ("In-andOut Conversions.", Matula, David W., Communications of the ACM 11, 1 (January 1986)) is quoted: to get `n` digits of base `b` from a base `B` representation you need `N = 2 + floor(n / log(b, B))` base `B` digits. With `n==7`, `b==10`, and `B == 2` you get `25`.

Answer (score 1):

I see a math proof like this:

```
-log10(2^(-24)) = 7.225
```

24 means include the 1 before the point. if not include the 1 before the point:

```
-log10(2^(-23)) = 6.9
```

Answer (score 0):

> [I] can't understand how a number like 1234567000000000 fits without loose "1,2,3,4,5,6,7" digits, what is the math behind this?

I don't quite understand your reasoning here. Anyway, here's how 1234567000000000 would be converted to a [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) [binary32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) (aka. [single](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format), aka float in C):

`1.09651577472686767578125 * 2**50`

Exponent is applied a bias (-127), mantissa and exponent are encoded in base 2, first bit of mantissa is dropped because it's always 1.

Check https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/ for yourself

As you could notice, the decimal value after conversion to a `float` is not equal to 1234567000000000, but about to 1234567008616448, and you can see the first 7 digits matches.

The loss of precision happen in the less significant digits due to the limited amount of bits used to encode the mantissa (also due to the conversion to base 2).

Comment: tnx for the answer, what I want to see is mathematical proof,I mean i can understand that the number 0.123456 can fits to mantissa because for digit '6'  10^-6 nearly equls to 2^20. But for number like 1234567000000 place value for '1' is 10^12 and

Comment: to be converted to a floating point IEEE-754, a real value is scaled to a base-2 value whose integral is equal to 1, to do so the real value is divided by a power of two, and that power will be used as the exponent. Then the fractional part of the base-2 value is truncated to fit in the 23bits of the mantissa. That truncation happen on less significant bits side.