# How to convert a big float into a string with commas without rounding

Tags: c#, rounding, string.format

I have a large float that I want to convert into a string with commas without rounding.

Here is what I have:

```
String.Format("{0:#,###}", val);
```

This turns 17154177 into 17,154,180
I would like to keep the commas but not round at the end using c#.

Comment: Are you sure this is a ***javascript*** question?

Comment: `String.Format` is not a native JavaScript method on the `String` object. Where are you getting that from? You could try [`toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [prevent rounding of decimals when using currency string format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6042262/prevent-rounding-of-decimals-when-using-currency-string-format)

Comment: @AndrewL64 No luck, still rounds at the end

Comment: This smells like a floating point rounding problem, not a string conversion problem.  Single-precision floating point values are only precise to [~6 significant digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50492868/3791245), but you want precision out to 8 digits.  Consider using `decimal` instead of `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Change your data type to decimal (28-29 significant digits) to have higher precision compared to float (7 digits).

Or you can change it to `var`. It will let the compiler figure out the best data type to use.

```
var number = 17154177;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:#,###}", number));
```

See this fiddler link, [working code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fJ2lVH)

Comment: Make that number you used into a float first and it does not work

Comment: You are right. You can also change it to decimal to make it 128 bits compare to float which only has 32 bits (7 digits). 

I updated my dotnet fiddle

Comment: I ended changing the datatype to double as soon as it came into the application from DB side

Comment: What is the database datatype of "17154177"?

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for

```cs
using System;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    float original = 17154177;

    // 1. Convert the number to a string
    string value = original.ToString("R");

    // 2. Reverse the string
    string reversed = Reverse(value);

    // 3. Add the comma on each third number, backwards
    string formatted = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < reversed.Length; i++) {
      if ((i+1) % 3 == 0) {
        formatted += reversed[i] + ",";
      } else {
        formatted += reversed[i];
      }
    }

    // 4. Reverse it back to the original order
    formatted = Reverse(formatted);

    Console.WriteLine (formatted);
  }

  /* Reverses a string */
  public static string Reverse(string text)
  {
    char[] cArray = text.ToCharArray();
    string reverse = String.Empty;
    for (int i = cArray.Length - 1; i > -1; i--)
    {
        reverse += cArray[i];
    }
    return reverse;
  }
}
```

I got the reverse method from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string).

Comment: I dont think this works well with floats, I got ,70+,E81,451,7.1 as the result

Comment: Let me check and see what I can do

Comment: I fixed the compatibility with floats. Just needed to add "R" inside `ToString`

Comment: You can see it working here: https://repl.it/repls/OrganicFlusteredText#main.cs

Comment: In this example, it rounds it down by 1 number

Comment: C# seems to still be rounding the last digit. Let me check once more and see if I can fix it

Comment: Seems to be working with `double`. Do you need the number to be a float?

Comment: The value comes in as a float from the database I will try to convert to see

Comment: If you could find a way to get the value from DB directly as a string, you could format it directly by using the comma concatenation I wrote

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3715741/8469219

Comment: I ended up changing value to double as soon as it came in from DB and it worked with the formatting i have

Comment: Yup. The problem in general was due to convertions. Glad you got it solved!